# Having Errors of Undefined offset: 2 in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Hi I am having some errors when I tried running my codes.
Here is my laravel blade. It shows undefined offset: 2 in this blade. Is this referring to an array or the offset for css?  I dont know where it means. Please help. thanks alot!

```
<h5 class="page-header"></h5>

        <div class="panel panel-success">
            @if($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
                    @endforeach
                </div> 
            @endif


                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">Add Transaction</h4>

                            </div>


                                    <div class="panel-body">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="DriverCommission" id="DriverCommission" value="<?php echo $TicketData[0]->amount;?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="EntranceFee" id="EntranceFee" value="<?php echo $TicketData[1]->amount;?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Complimentary" id="Complimentary" value="<?php echo $TicketData[2]->amount;?>">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('Current Entrance Fee:') }}

                                            {{ Form::text('P',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '60', 'id' => 'EntranceFee','required' , 'readonly']) }}
                                        </div>  


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('No. of Guest(s) :') }}
                                            {{ Form::text('particular',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'id' => 'particular' ,'required']) }}
                                        </div>  




                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('Amount of Ticket :') }}

                                            {{ Form::text('P',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'id' => 'ticket_amount','required' , 'readonly']) }}
                                        </div>  


                                        <div class="form-group">

                                             {{ Form::checkbox('agree', 1, null, ['class' => 'field' , 'id' => 'WithDriver']) }}
                                             {{ Form::label('w/ Tourist Driver') }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">

                                             {{ Form::checkbox('agree', 1, null, ['class' => 'field' , 'id' => 'Complimentary']) }}
                                             {{ Form::label('Complimentary (P0.00)') }}
                                        </div>

                                <div class="center"><button type="button" id="btnContinue" {{-- data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  --}} class="btn btn-success">Continue</button></div>

                                </div>
                    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Transaction Details</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                                    {{ Form::open((['url' => 'ticket/transact'])) }}

                                        <input type="hidden" name="DriverCommission" id="DriverCommission" value="<?php echo $TicketData[0]->amount;?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="EntranceFee" id="EntranceFee" value="<?php echo $TicketData[1]->amount;?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Complimentary" id="Complimentary" value="<?php echo $TicketData[2]->amount;?>">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="is_driver" id="is_driver" value="0">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_min_range" id="ticket_min_range" value="">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_max_range" id="ticket_max_range" value="">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <h6 class="right-align" id="ticketNumberText">Ticket Number(s):</h6>
                                        </div>      

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('No. of Ticket(s) :') }}
                                            {{ Form::text('no_of_tickets',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '' , 'id'=>"modal_tickets" ,'required' ,'readonly']) }}
                                        </div>      

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('Total Price :') }}

                                            {{ Form::text('total_price',null,['id'=>"modal_totalprice" ,'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '','required' ,'readonly']) }}
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('Amount Tendered :') }}

                                            {{ Form::text('amount_tendered',null,['id'=>"modal_tendered" ,'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '','required']) }}
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::label('Change :') }}

                                            {{ Form::text('amount_change',null,['id'=>"modal_change" ,'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '','required' , 'readonly']) }}
                                        </div>  


                                <div class="form-group">
                                            {{ Form::submit('Save Transaction',['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
                                        </div>

                                    {{ Form::close() }}
                                </div> 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).on("keyup" , "#particular" , function (){
    CalulateAmount();
   });

  $(document).on("change" , "#WithDriver" , function (){
    if(($('#WithDriver').is(":checked"))){
        $("#is_driver").val(1);
    }
    else{
        $("#is_driver").val(0);
    }
});

function CalulateAmount(){

    var NumberOfTickets = $("#particular").val();
    var EntranceFee = $("#EntranceFee").val();
    var DriverCommision = $("#DriverCommission").val();


    var Amount = (NumberOfTickets*EntranceFee);

    $("#modal_tickets").val(NumberOfTickets);       
    $("#modal_totalprice").val(Amount);

    $("#ticket_amount").val(Amount);

}

$(document).on("keyup" , "#modal_tendered" , function (){

    var TotalPrice = $("#modal_totalprice").val();
    var Tendered = this.value;

    var Change = (Tendered - TotalPrice) ;

    $("#modal_change").val(Change);

});

$(document).on("click" , ".btnReset" , function (){
    $("#modal_tendered").val("");
    $("#modal_change").val("");
});

$(document).on("click" , "#btnContinue" , function (){

    $.ajax({
            url: '{{ URL::to("admin/CheckLastticketUsed") }}',
            type: 'GET',
            data : { total_tickets : $("#particular").val()  },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if(data.status == true){                        
                        console.log(data.ticket_ranges);
                        $("#ticket_min_range").val(data.start_range);
                        $("#ticket_max_range").val(data.end_range);
                        $("#ticketNumberText").html("Ticket Number(s):"+        data.ticket_ranges);
                }
                else{

                }
            };

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }
    });

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

});

</script> 
@stop
```

HEre is my function:

```
   class TPController extends Controller
  {
   public function index()
  {
    return view('tp.tpIndex');
}

public function transactTicket()
{
    $GetTicketData = Chap_ticket::where('id' ,4)->Orwhere('id' ,5)->Orwhere('id' ,8)->get(); 
    return view('tp.transactTicket')->with('TicketData', $GetTicketData);
}

public function submitTicket(Request $request){


    //return $request->all();
    $min = $request->ticket_min_range;
    $max = $request->ticket_max_range;
    // return "min: $min max: $max";

    $ticket_numbers = array();
    for ($i=$min; $i <= $max; $i++) { 

        Entrance_ticket::where('ticket_number', $i)
                  ->update(['is_use' => 1]);
    }
    die();
    // return view('tp.transactTicket')->with('TicketData', $GetTicketData);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I updated the question..

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for this error? Knowing which line is complaining about the undefined offset would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment these lines in your view:

```php
<input type="hidden" name="Complimentary" id="Complimentary" value="<?php echo $TicketData[2]->amount;?>">
```

The error you're facing is related to accessing the `$TicketData`, you have typed this line twice in your code I believe if you comment them your view will work just fine.

Comment: sorry I overlooked id number of the tickets. its working now. no error on the page but its not computing the total amount of price :(